# Linear Algebra Eigenbasis Proof Help

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let T be the orthogonal projection on a subspace V of Rn. Proven T has an orthonormal eigenbasis. (I already proved this part with the eigenvalues of T being 0 and 1)

**Let S be the reflection about a subspace V of Rn. Prove that S also has an orthonormal eigenbasis.**

For this I have found S has the eigenvalues 1 and -1 because of a theorem which states "the possible real eigenvalues of an orthogonal matrix are 1 and -1."

I'm not sure where to go from here, please help solve the bolded part. :)

Comment: Are you assuming that $S$ has an orthogonal matrix?

Comment: Yes. S is the matrix [v1 v2 v3 ... vn] where Av1 = lambdav1 ...lambdavn= Avn. And not sure if knowing the B matrix helps at all, but it is the matrix with the eigenvalues on the diagonal. And S and B will diagonalize A, so S-1AS=B. Also remember T(x)=Ax.

Answer (score 0):

We can find an orthonormal eigenbasis explicitly in each case in the following way:

Let $v_1,\dots,v_d$ be an orthonormal eigenbasis of $V$.  Extend this to an orthonormal eigenbasis $v_1,\dots,v_n$ of $\Bbb R^n$, noting that $v_{d+1},\dots,v_n$ are orthogonal to $V$.

Verify that these are eigenvectors of $S$ and $T$.  Note the associated eigenvalues.

Comment: That's how I proved T. I guess I'm confused about why you would use an eigenbasis perpendiculat/orthogonal to V to prove S with the eigenvalues being 1 and -1. I thought you did that for T because they were 1 and 0.

Comment: Note that if $u$ is in $V^\perp$, $T(u) = -u$ (whereas $S(u)  = 0$).